# Is it acceptable to attach elevated deck joists to rafter tails?

Tags: framing, deck, safety

I'm having an attached patio built by a contractor. I am concerned about the quality of the construction. In particular the attachment of the patio joists to the house rafters. Instead of using a ledger board, our contractor has simply attached the patio joists to the rafters using nails. Is this safe?

[image: Patio Attached to rafters]

[image: Full View]

Comment: Reading between the lines, it sounds like you don't have a building permit for this. If you did, the inspection would clear up this question. Please clarify, though, if this is roofed, open rafters, or floor for a second level.

Comment: Is this a platform intended to support human weight? 2x6 joists at 24" centers are not adequate, even with a ledger and steel hangers.

Answer (score 2):

If the building inspector stopped at your job he would put a stop order on it.  You should have a 2x6 or 2x8 bolted to the house framing and then run your rafters or joists what every they may be from that using joist hangers.

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't look like a patio.  the patio is the area you stand on, not the roof overhead.  this looks like a pergola.  if it gets covered, then its a roof.  either way, its not okay to build it that way (at least according to the Ontario building code)

Answer (score 1):

Not very strong and certainly not as strong as if you had a ledger board.

Why not just have your contractor add a ledger board under the ends of the patio rafters? Tell him that's the way you want it and you want the ledger board lagged into the house.

You're the one buying so have it like you want it.

Good luck with your project!